# Full Text Search is not working properly in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have created a Full Text search Catalog in SQL Server and performing through asp.net application but it's not working properly.

My Scenario is: I have a doc file and for first time when I will search the text (`Demo`) then it shows the result but when I do change in doc file and insert another `Demo` text then it doesn't show the inserted text in full search.

Please let me know if there is way to rebuild or any operation to do with catalog.

Please Help me ASAP and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this "doc file"?

Comment: doc file means microsoft word 2003 format file.

Comment: It can be Word File ,Text File or an Xml File

Answer (score 0):

First verify that full-text searching is configured correctly in SQL Server

1. On your server running SQL Server, click Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Serve , and then click Enterprise Manager .
2. In the left pane, expand the Microsoft SQL Servers node.
3. Expand the SQL Server Group node, and then expand the server instance that is running your SharePoint databases.
4. Expand the Databases node.
5. Right-click the Northwind database, click New , and then click New Full-Text Catalog .

   If the Northwind database is not installed, you can use any other available database.
6. In the Name box, type a name to use for the catalog (such as "test"), and then click OK .
7. In the right pane, double-click Full-Text Catalogs .

   Your new full-text catalog should be listed. If the catalog was created without any errors, full-text searching is working correctly in SQL Server. If there were errors creating this test catalog, there were probably errors creating the catalogs for your SharePoint sites. The SQL Server Full-Text service must be working before full-text searches in your SharePoint sites can work. For more information about configuring full-text searching, see "Administering Full-Text Features Using SQL Enterprise Manager" in SQL Server 2000 Books Online. Contact Microsoft Support if there are issues that you cannot resolve.

   After you have verified that the catalog was created successfully, you can delete the test catalog.
8. Right-click the catalog, and then click Delete .
9. On the confirmation message, click Yes .